# MS SQL how to take out few unique rows when I don't know their specific values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table1 that is all about courses at university, which Employees can run them and it looks like this:

[image]

It is built on few joins and grouped by StudySemester, SchoolSubjectId, EmployeeId. StudySemester is actually an id which refers to first year of Informatics for example. 
I want to take some data out, want to get something like this:

[image]

Where only one of few available Employees was assigned to a specific course and I want it done randomly. I.e Employees 13, 15, 17 could teach ePhs, StudySemester = 1000, however there should be one chosen - Employee 15 for example but it could be 13 or 17 as well, doesn’t matter. 
I don’t know these exact values that’s why I can’t write … WHERE EmployeeId = 15. Is there any way?

Sorry if my post wasn’t clear enough, I am writing here first time. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` function with `newid()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by CourseSchoolSubjectId, StudySemester order by newid()) as seq
      from table t
     )
where seq = 1;
```

Comment: Works. Thank you so much.